# axios how to get data from inside of round brackets

Tags: reactjs, axios, request

I want to need extract data from inside this round bracket.
I have this response was a string type.what should i do....

```
test({
  coord: { lon: -0.1257, lat: 51.5085 },
  weather: [{ id: 721, main: "Haze", description: "haze", icon: "50d" }],
  base: "stations",
  main: {
    temp: 57.09,
    feels_like: 56.88,
    temp_min: 51.57,
    temp_max: 60.89,
    pressure: 1015,
    humidity: 93,
  },
  visibility: 5000,
  wind: { speed: 3.44, deg: 0 },
  clouds: { all: 94 },
  dt: 1631945495,
  sys: {
    type: 2,
    id: 2019646,
    country: "GB",
    sunrise: 1631943620,
    sunset: 1631988544,
  },
  timezone: 3600,
  id: 2643743,
  name: "London",
  cod: 200,
});
```

This is my request but it returns undefined:

```
axios.request(options).then( (response) => {
    console.log(response.data.coord.lon);
}).catch((error)  => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

Comment: Please try formatting the first block of code, it is not readable written in one line. Besides, there is no `data.country` in your response (if that object is in fact your response). There is `data.sys.country`.

Comment: I was try your way and tried many ways.but i have return error. eg   i try response.coord.lon.  sorry i am not define one thing and now i checked this response to i use javascript  typeOf method  i notice . this response is not a object, not a array ,i have a return string value. what should i do.